# Sort JsonArray of JsonObjects Java

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, gson

I'm Using Gson Library.I need to sort an JsonArray of JsonObjects based on keys in the JsonObjects.The JsonArray is given below

```
[{"AS1000":["5.1","0","false","false",null,null],"AS2000":["-","-","-","-","-","-"],"Date":"2014-03-02 08:07:00.0"},
{"AS1000":["5.0","0","false","false",null,null],"AS2000":["-","-","-","-","-","-"],"Date":"2014-03-02 17:58:00.0"},
{"AS1000":["5.0","0","false","false",null,null],"AS2000":["-","-","-","-","-","-"],"Date":"2014-03-30 14:59:00.0"},
{"AS1000":["-","-","-","-","-","-"],"AS2000":["27.0","0","true","false","30.0 - 20.0",null],"Date":"2014-03-30 06:03:00.0"},
{"AS1000":["-","-","-","-","-","-"],"AS2000":["15.0","0","false","false",null,null],"Date":"2014-03-02 02:00:00.0"},
{"AS1000":["5.0","0","false","false",null,null],"AS2000":["-","-","-","-","-","-"],"Date":"2014-03-14 20:06:00.0"},
{"AS1000":["5.0","0","false","false",null,null],"AS2000":["-","-","-","-","-","-"],"Date":"2014-03-30 07:00:00.0"},
{"AS1000":["-","-","-","-","-","-"],"AS2000":["61.0","0","false","false",null,null],"Date":"2014-03-17 19:07:59.0"}]
```

Is it possible to sort based on keys in the object for example AS2000[0] or Date?

I have tried Boon like this

```
        JsonArray listLoggerDataObj=gson.fromJson(listloggerdata, JsonArray.class);
        List<JsonObject> list=new ArrayList<JsonObject>();
         for (JsonElement entry : listLoggerDataObj) {
         list.add(entry.getAsJsonObject());
         }


        sort(list,"Date"); /*list ,key used to sort*/
        System.out.println("printing sorted" +list.toString());
```

But it prints the same input.Any Ideas?

Thanks,

Gowrish

Comment: Can you share the *sort(...)* method? I think your problem with it.

Comment: Use Collections.sort with a custom comparator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property)

Comment: @veysiertekin sort is a part of boon library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution.Used Boon's jsonParser to construct Json from string (not Gson's fromJson()) and then casted into List,finally applied sort(),Issue Fixed.

```
  Object jsonObject = fromJson(listloggerdata);
  List<?> jsonDepartments = (List<?>) jsonObject;

  sort(jsonDepartments,sortBy("Date"));

  System.out.println("printing sorted" +jsonDepartments.toString());
```

the sorted result is

```
[{"AS2000":["15.0","0","false","false",null,null],"AS1000":["-","-","-","-","-","-"],"Date":"2014-03-02 02:00:00.0"},
 {"AS2000":["-","-","-","-","-","-"],"AS1000":["5.1","0","false","false",null,null],"Date":"2014-03-02 08:07:00.0"},
 {"AS2000":["-","-","-","-","-","-"],"AS1000":["5.0","0","false","false",null,null],"Date":"2014-03-02 17:58:00.0"},
 {"AS2000":["-","-","-","-","-","-"],"AS1000":["5.0","0","false","false",null,null],"Date":"2014-03-14 20:06:00.0"},
 {"AS2000":["61.0","0","false","false",null,null],"AS1000":["-","-","-","-","-","-"],"Date":"2014-03-17 19:07:59.0"},
 {"AS2000":["27.0","0","true","false","30.0 - 20.0",null],"AS1000":["-","-","-","-","-","-"],"Date":"2014-03-30 06:03:00.0"},
 {"AS2000":["-","-","-","-","-","-"],"AS1000":["5.0","0","false","false",null,null],"Date":"2014-03-30 07:00:00.0"},
 {"AS2000":["-","-","-","-","-","-"],"AS1000":["5.0","0","false","false",null,null],"Date":"2014-03-30 14:59:00.0"}]
```

You can even sort based on array index like this

```
 sort(jsonDepartments,sortByDesending("AS2000[0]"));
```

Hope this might help someone.

Comment: Any idea how can you do this with Gson's fromJson()?

Answer (score -4):

I have also used Boon library but i am getting error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError org.boon.sort.Sort"

Please tell me if i am doing something wrong .

```
            this.list = global.getPartyPartneruserlistwithstatus().getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("in_list");


            List<JSONObject> list1 = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
            for (int i = 0; i < global.getPartyPartneruserlistwithstatus().getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("in_list").length(); i++) {
                    list1.add(list.getJSONObject(i));
            }

                sort(list1,"age");
```

and list contains JSONARRAY in

[
    {
        "username": "Navdeep Singh Sandhu",
        "hometown": "chandigarh",
        "request_id": "2",
        "social_id": "100002878462251",
        "social_provider": "facebook",
        "age": 25
    },
    {
        "username": "HarPreet Kaur",
        "hometown": "chandigarh",
        "request_id": "4",
        "social_id": "100002029425217",
        "social_provider": "facebook",
        "age": 23
    }]